# The only function that forms a homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_n$ to $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Define $M_a : Z_n → Z_n$ by $M_a([x]) = [ax]$

Prove that

(a) $M_a$ : $(Z_n, +) → (Z_n, +)$ is a homomorphism.

(b) Let φ : $(Z_n, +) → (Z_n, +)$ be a homomorphism. Prove that φ = $M_a$ for some a ∈ Z.

(c) For two homomorphism φ, ψ : $(Z_n, +) → (Z_n, +)$, prove that if φ = $M_a and ψ = M_b$, then for
their composition φ ◦ ψ = $M_{ab}$.

My attempt:
(a) is just using the definition of homomorphism and knowing that $[ax+ay]_n=[ax]_n +[ay]_n$

(c) involved simply using definitions of these functions as well.

I do not know how to prove (b):
Using the fact that the function has been given to be a homomorphism, what I do is:

$ψ(0 + a) = ψ(0) + ψ (a)$

This means $ψ (a) = [0]_n$
But I do not see how this will help me conclude the function must be of the form $M_a$
Could someone please help or provide an alternative?

Comment: Note that $\varphi([k]) = \varphi([1]+\cdots+[1]) = \varphi([1])+\cdots+\varphi([1])$, where the sums have $k$ summands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\in\mathbb Z$ be such that $\varphi(1)=[a]$. Then $\varphi(1)=M_a(1)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_n=\langle1\rangle$, you deduce from this that $\varphi=M_a$.